# CD-ROM drive fails to open/recognize inserted cd in Legacy boot mode

Tags: uefi, data-cd, audio-cd

Recently I wanted to check that I'm able to read cd/dvd disks. No my surprise my "old" laptop failed to do so. After investigating today I've found out cd drive works on Linux Mint 17.x booted in both legacy and UEFI modes and for Linux Mint 20 it works only if booted in UEFI mode.

In Legacy mode LM 20 first terminal command `eject sr0` took a long time, drive had not opened, next time it returned immediately w/out any visible effect. `journalctl` shows nothing at that time, overall near the end `ata2.00: revalidation failed`. If drive is open with external button, inserted cd disk is not shown in `disks` GUI (`no media`, CD/DVD drive itself is shown as `/dev/sr0`).

Why is there a difference how I boot the distro? Where/what to investigate further? I'd like to understand and fix the issue. TIA

Answer (score 1):

I also have an old laptop whose DVD drive sometimes fails to open, but it seems to be caused by the poor connection between the laptop and the hot-pluggable DVD module. (In that laptop model, it was/is an option to replace the DVD module with a second battery.) Removing & re-plugging the DVD module for a few times seems to help... perhaps it would be about time to treat the DVD module connectors with Deoxit or similar.

The log message `ata2.00: revalidation failed` suggests the system has trouble communicating with the drive, so it might be an intermittent connection issue rather than dependent on the boot mode.

If you have repeatably proven the boot mode actually matters, then it's likely to be a firmware issue, and only a firmware update (even with UEFI, many vendors still call them "BIOS updates" for familiarity's sake) might help.

Some CD/DVD drives themselves have had firmware updates released for them over the years. Although CD/DVD drives are pretty old and well-known technology these days, firmware bugs are still possible within the drive itself too.

So, check with the laptop vendor's support page for your specific laptop model, and see if there are any BIOS or other firmware updates available. If you find any, read the firmware release notes to see if anything relevant-sounding has been fixed in between the version you currently have and the latest available version.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I posted it in unix cause I tested it to work with one linux distro but not with the other. So I don't see it as firmware only issue, but rather as communication between the drivers and firmware, older driver works.

Comment: The driver used in UEFI and legacy modes is *exactly the same* in both modes, and you said the newer distro works in UEFI mode.The "revalidation failed" message comes from the `ata_dev_revalidate` function `drivers/ata/libata-core.c` of Linux kernel, which is not specific to CD/DVD drives at all. The function is called after a bus reset or other error event, to verify the device is still present. That suggests an intermittent hardware issue. With intermittent faults, it's easy to misattribute the issue to some change you made, when actually the fault comes and goes randomly.